# Is there a best practice for where to put global variables which are shared across files?

Tags: angular, typescript, variables

There is a list of data that I share across files that I want to keep constant across all the site's pages but the data might change over time. I was thinking that it would be a good idea to put all these data in a communal file so that I don't have to change 50 lines of code in 50 different locations every time one of these variables change and I will know where to go whenever I want to change such variables, but I don't know which file to put all these variables in.

Is there some "best practice" on where to put these variables in? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can maintain Environment File and access all around files

make environment.ts file

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  api_url: 'https://Your_Api/api'
};
```

Access Those data

```
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
```

then access Data

```
if (environment.production) {
  //your logic
}
```